# How can I translate the webpage opened via Selenium Webdriver to English using Python?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

This is my code so far:

```
username_input = "username"
password_input = "password"
url='myurl'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(r'chromedriver.exe')
browser.get(url)
browser.maximize_window()
username = browser.find_element_by_id("j_username")
password = browser.find_element_by_id("j_password")
username.send_keys(str(username_input))
password.send_keys(str(password_input))
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="inner-box"]/form/label[3]/input').click()
time.sleep(2)
```

Once I have logged in everything is in French but I need it in English.. how do I do this?

I have tried several things such as Chrome Options but didn't understand it/wasn't working.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking for an English to French translator, or are you asking how to configure the site to display in English?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add `prefs` below to auto translate french to english

```
options = Options()
prefs = {
  "translate_whitelists": {"fr":"en"},
  "translate":{"enabled":"true"}
}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

you can remove `r'chromedriver.exe'` if the location is in same folder with your script.

Comment: This gives me TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'option'

Comment: Instead of "browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)" it was meant to be "browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)" .. Thank you a lot for this code, it worked!

Answer (score 2):

The correct solution is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_path = "D:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver"
custom_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {
  "translate_whitelists": {"ru":"en"},
  "translate":{"enabled":"true"}
}
custom_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path, options=custom_options)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have to set up Chrome options like:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--lang=en")
```

Comment: this looks simpler but it did not work for me

Comment: This is not worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The change of webpage language is determined by the browser settings. I tried practically almost all the strategies discussed and mentioned in the forum, but none of them worked for me. I was able to successfully achieve it by following the instructions outlined below.

1. Create a new Chrome profile (i.e. Profile 2). Then move the new profile directory in the "Documents" directory of "Users"
2. Now open Google Chrome (from new profile), "run as administrator" mode > open [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) > at the bottom of the page, click on "setting" > now click on "search setting" > select the "region setting" > select "United Kingdom" for opening the webpage only in English language.
3. Now follow the following java code snippet.

   `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Testing Work` `Space\\chromedriver.exe");`

// Chrome actual new profile path is "C:\Users\shah\Documents\Profile 2\"

// but you have to keep the chromeProfilePath till "\Documents\" as follows

```
String chromeProfilePath = "C:\\Users\\shah\\Documents\\";
ChromeOptions chroOption = new ChromeOptions();
chroOption.addArguments("user-data-dir=" + chromeProfilePath);
```

// Here you specify the new Chrome profile folder (Profile 2)

```
chroOption.addArguments("profile-directory=Profile 2");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chroOption);
driver.get("https://facebook.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

All other answers not working for me. And I found bruteforce solution:

```
import pyautogui

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


url = 'https://ifconfig.me/'

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--lang=fr')  # set your language here

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

browser.get(url)

actionChains = ActionChains(browser)
actionChains.context_click().perform()

# here maybe problem. Debug it:
for i in range(3):
    pyautogui.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.press('up')

pyautogui.press('enter')
```

Answer (score 0):

As of September 2022, It seems like setting `prefs` doesn't work for chrome version 105. In order to solve this, you can either downgrade your chrome to version 95 or use selenium standalone docker. For the docker approach, You should pull and run standalone docker using:

```
docker pull selenium/standalone-chrome:95.0-chromedriver-95.0-20211102
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 --shm-size="2g" selenium/standalone-chrome:95.0-chromedriver-95.0-20211102
```

Then in your code use remoteDriver and apply prefs like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--lang=en')
prefs = {
    "translate_whitelists": {"es": "en"},
    "translate": {"enabled": "true"}
}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', options=options)
driver.get("https://www.amazon.es/")
```