# Translate a page: Selenium in R

Tags: r, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to translate a webpage from Hindi to English by passing experimental options to `chromedriver` in R while using the `rselenium` package.

I am using the following setup but I am not able to translate the page automatically to English. This builds on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54042910/how-can-i-translate-the-webpage-opened-via-selenium-webdriver-to-english-using-p).

```
eCaps <- list(prefs = list(translate_whitelists=c('hi:en'), translate=c('enabled:true')))
rd <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome",
               chromever = "84.0.4147.30",
               port = netstat::free_port(),
               extraCapabilities = eCaps)
```

Any help in getting this to work is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Figured this out. The following code does the trick.

`eCaps <- list(chromeOptions = list(args = c('--disable-gpu','--window-size=1920,1080', '--lang=en'),
                                   prefs = list(translate_whitelists=list('hi' = 'en'), translate=list('enabled'='true'))))`

Comment: You should make it an answer for improved visibility (and readability)